# Async/await with Context Api Hooks - React

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, react-context

Im using Context API to manage my app global state, and im trying to do that using hooks for the first time... and im having a little trouble with async/await, let me explain:

This is my provider:

```
const JobProvider = (props) => {
       const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
       const [modalJob, setModalJob] = useState({})
       const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([])
       const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('')
       const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
       const [now, setNow] = useState('')


       const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
           setSearchItem(e.target.value)
       }


     const getJob = id => {
        // bla bla bla 
        return something;
       };

// ... 

 }
```

And inside that Provider i have a function **nextPage()** that only updates the page number and return it after that... heres the Provider with that function:

```
const JobProvider = (props) => {
           const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
           const [modalJob, setModalJob] = useState({})
           const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([])
           const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('')
           const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
           const [now, setNow] = useState('')


           const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
               setSearchItem(e.target.value)
           }


         const getJob = id => {
            // bla bla bla 
            return something;
           };


         async function nextPage() {
           await setPage(page + 1)
           console.log(page)
         }

    // ...
```

}

but first is logging the page and only after the state page is updated. There are any way to do this?

Comment: `setPage` does not return a promise, so you cannot await on it. you can however you a `useEffect` to log the value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do a await and set the state, because it doesn't work in that way. Thats why we use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook

so when page changes you can do your functionality, useEffect second parameter accepts an array of dependencies, whenever it gets change it will trigger

```
useEffect(() => {
 // do your logic
}, [page])
```

whenever page changes it will call and dont call **useEffect** inside if conditions or functions